# How do you change the font when using fncychap?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, fncychap

I am using `fncychap` and would like to use a different font for the chapter label than the rest of the document. Is there any easy and general way?

Comment: Please provide some more information about your computing setup. E.g., do you use pdf(la)tex, xe(la)tex, or lua(la)tex -- or something else? Which documentclass do you use? And, which fonts are you currently using and/or looking to use for the chapter headings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact configuration depends on the `fncychap` style you’re using, but in general, there are a few macros for adapting the style, as described in section 2.1 of the [`fncychap` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/fncychap). The ones for changing the font etc. are `\ChNameVar{stuff}`, `\ChNumVar{stuff}` and `\ChTitleVar{stuff}`. Here’s an example for the style `Sonny` using pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
  % defaults:
  %\ChNameVar{\Large\sf}
  %\ChNumVar{\Huge}
  %\ChTitleVar{\Large\sf}
  % custom:
  \ChNameVar{\Large\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\color{blue}}
  \ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\color{red}}
  \ChTitleVar{\Large\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\scshape\color{green}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello World!}
Foo bar baz
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

For some more details on how to change the font and also how to do it with XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or ConTeXt, see [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/4012).

Also note that in some `fncychap` styles, variables influence the following variables; e.g. in my example, “Hello World!” and the rules would be red if I hadn’t specified their color. I’m not sure if that’s a bug or intended behavior.

Comment: the downside is on other styles it change position of title to left