# Changing font colour in fncychap

Tags: fonts, sectioning, color, chapters, fncychap

I am using the Lenny chapter style from `fncychap` and I would like to change the colour of the chapter number. I found ["How do you change the font when using fncychap?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89922/how-do-you-change-the-font-when-using-fncychap) and followed the recommendations there to produce:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{60}{62}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

This almost works, but has the unfortunate side-effect of changing the colour of the box too. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\textcolor` rather than `\color`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChNumVar{\fontsize{60}{62}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}\selectfont\textcolor{blue}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
Lorem ipsum
\chapter{Another Title}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Simple and works perfectly.